# Run-time check failure#0 when using Append function of msado21.tlh

Tags: c++, com, ado

I am using msado21.tlh to append record in recordset. But the Append function causes runtime check failure#0 error. I searched about the error and came to know its related to calling convention. I am not able to solve this error. Please help.

I am using Visual studio 2012, OS is windows server 2008 R2 SP1, 64 bit machine.
I am having a web site application which uses a C++ application which is a window service(32bit). This C++ application uses msado21.tlb. The calling convention set in project properties is __cdecl(/Gd) and the path for msado21 is set to C:\program files\common files\system\ado. Also, inside IIS manager the flag for enabling 32 bit process in AppPool is set to true.
But if I use msado21.tlb from C:\program files(x86)\common files\system\ado then everything works fine. I am unable to understand what is the root cause of this problem and how to resolve it?
Please provide some guidance.
Thanks

Comment: You have un-initialized variables.

Comment: ADO 2.1 is very, very old.  The Fields interface has an Append() method, it was updated at Windows 7 SP1 to fix a type library bug that made it difficult to use it in 64-bit code.  You'll need to use the #import directive to generate the .tlh file, do make sure you are not using a .tlh file that was generated in the previous century.  Whether any of this applies is hard to tell, we're flying blind here without anything at all to look at.

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks for your reply. As you suggested that I need to generate .tlh file, could you be more clear. I am using #import "masdo21.tlb" no_namespace rename("EOF", "gtEOF") and the tlb path in project properties is set to C:\program files\common files\system\ado. But I am still facing the issue